# how to append columns in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this,

```
data = {'first_column':  ['first_sentence', 'second_sentence'], 'second_column': ['A', 'B'],         'third_column' : ['C', 'D'] }
```

The original structure like this

> first_column  second_column   third_column
>
> first_sentence             A                           C
>
> second_sentence     B                         D

I want to convert it into following format

> first_column   column
>
> first_sentence       A
>
> first_sentence        C
>
> second_sentence    B
>
> second_sentence    D

I tried `df.stack()`

but it gives

> 0  first_column      first_sentence
>
> second_column                  A
>
> third_column                       C
>
> 1  first_column     second_sentence
>
> second_column                  B
>
> third_column                      D

I have around 27 columns in original dataframe and i want to produce 1 column, how can i do this

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `melt`:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['first_column'], value_vars=['second_column', 'third_column'], value_name='column')
        .sort_values(by="first_column").drop(['variable'], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with `melt` here is the output. You should have A B C D and not A C B D?

Comment: @Corralien unless the data is panel/longitudinal, the arrangement does not matter

Comment: @Corralien I sorted the values by first_column and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_index` before `stack`:

```
out= df.set_index('first_column').stack().droplevel(1).rename('column').reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
      first_column column
0   first_sentence      A
1   first_sentence      C
2  second_sentence      B
3  second_sentence      D
```